# How do I change the collation for a CRM 2011 SQL database?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a collection of CRM 2011 databases, all of which are installed on the same SQL server running SQL 2008 R2.  One of those databases has a collation of `Modern_Spanish_Cl_Al`, while all of the others are set to `Latin1_General_Cl_Al`.  I want all of them to be set to Latin1, so I would like to go back and fix the Spanish database to be like the others.

How do I change the database collation from `Modern_Spanish_Cl_Al` to `Latin1_General_Cl_Al`?

I tried doing it at the database level using the UI, but I received a million errors like:

**The statistics 'TeamBase.fndx_Sync_VersionNumber' is dependent on database collation. The database collation cannot be changed if a schema-bound object depends on it. Remove the dependencies on the database collation and then retry the operation.**

I tried going to the column level while also using the UI, but received a different error message:

**Saving changes is not permitted.  The changes you have made require the following tables to be dropped and re-created...**

I am dealing with this issue in a test environment, so I am willing to experiment, and I realize that what I am trying to do might not be possible without breaking CRM.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try creating a new DB with the correct collation

```
CREATE DATABASE DatabaseName COLLATE Latin1_General_Cl_Al;
```

And then Backup-Restore your DB with incorrect collation into the new one?
Should this work, you'll have to import a new organization based on your new database, using the Import Organization Wizard in the Deployment Manager.

**edit**

After looking into this, it seems quite hard to change collation, even when doing backup/restore.
Your only option if you want to change the collation on the database level seems to be an

```
ALTER DATABASE ... COLLATE
```

but that will only affect new objects. You would then have to use ALTER TABLE to change your existing tables.

In addition, because the collation specifies how data is sorted and stored, you need to export all your data and bring it in again (using BCP and BULK INSERT for instance).

To add to this, certain properties of a column prevents its collation from being changed (such as certain constraints and schema bound function references). If you do want to change the collation of the entire database, the easiest way is probably to script the database and create a new with the right collation and then shuffle the data into the new database.

Comment: Has anyone ever successfully done this before for a CRM 2011 database?

Comment: Done what exactly? The scripting and recreating?

Comment: Changed the collation for a CRM 2011 SQL database by following the process outlined in this answer.